# Router MAC address does not match with the actual one

Tags: router, mac

from my PC Windows 10 I am doing an `arp -a` to lookup the MAC of my router/modem.
I get something like:

```
 Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.1           90-5c-66-27-eb-70     dynamic
```

Now, such MAC is none of the 3x MAC addresses printed behind the device. So I am wondering why I am seeing a different MAC?

Real MAC: 90:5C:44:19:8F:79
Connection from my PC is WiFi.

thanks.

Comment: 90-5c-66-27-eb-70 does not look like a valid MAC address (in sense it neighther has been assigned to a company nor looks like a valid private MAC). Maybe You should post the addresses printed on the device and the device type. Also the connection type between Your Windows 10 device  and router/modem could be from interest.

Comment: @EOhm Real MAC: 90:5C:44:19:8F:79 and I am conencting WiFi. I suspect as well that that MAC is not a true one..

Answer (score 1):

Basically MAC addresses can be spoofed by hardware.
But for the Real MAC I can find a owner https://hwaddress.com/?q=90%3A5C%3A44%3A19%3A8F%3A79.

So possibly nothing wrong and the "3x MAC addresses printed behind the device" are just some special purpose MACs worth printing them.
It's not not commonly needed to know MAC addreeses of devices for end customer, but they want customers to find the HFC MAC ID to tell them their cable provider to enable the internet connection of box.

For that sepcifc `Compal Broadband Networks CH6640E` in addition the the HFC (Hybrid Fibre-Coax => the address of the cable modem on the side connecting to cable ISP via fibre-coax cable used for setting up the connection, communication of modem with provider equipment etc.) MAC there is a MTA (Multimedia Terminal Adapter => a telephony/VOIP specific part of the modem, used to connect to provider side through the HFC connection) MAC and a "Gateway MGMT" (I assume that is the CPE / Customer Premise Equipment) MAC that is the one joining the IP network in Your router.

These three addresses could be asked for by Your cable modem provider for service setup and trouble shooting. All the other is just some local stuff no one cares about. (If You need the MAC there will be a way to get it, if You cannot communicate with that divce You do not need the MAC. Most customers do not even understand what an IP address is so and they are not supposed to get in touch with MAC addresses.)

Comment: thanks. "These three addresses could be asked for by Your cable modem provider for service setup and trouble shooting. All the other is just some local stuff no one cares about.". Indeed I only see 3x labels printed, so what is "all the other stuff..."?

Comment: The WLAN and LAN chips have some (typically WLAN can have more then one, so one for 2.4, one for 5 GHz, maybe a virtual one), Maybe some internal switch, probably not much more.  My Fritz Box seems to have at least 3 for WLAN, one the client sees independent on whether connected to 2.4 or 5 GHz, one for 2.4 interface and one for 5 GHz interface. The interface MACs are visible in UI of the box and probably as the MACs if the AP the client connects to, but the IP connection terminates to another one. Probably there is one or two such MACs more for the Guest Access WLAN AP. LAN additional...